# Android try with resources no method found close()

Tags: java, android, try-with-resources

I am using android `MediaMetaDataRetriever` which implements `AutoCloseable` in an android application. I have the below code

```java
try (final MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever()) {
    retriever.setDataSource(videoUri.getPath());
    return retriever.getFrameAtTime(10, getFrameOption());
}
```

minSDK > 21

but I am getting the following crash

`No virtual method close()V in class Landroid/media/MediaMetadataRetriever; or its super classes (declaration of ‘android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever’ appears in /system/framework/framework.jar`

how can this happen if `MediaMetadataRetriever implements AutoCloseable`

Comment: What API level are you using?

Comment: I don't work on this project any more but I will as one of the developers who does to comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can this happen if `MediaMetadataRetriever implements AutoCloseable`.

Because `MediaMetadataRetriever` did not implement `AutoCloseable` [until API 29](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/29/changes/android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever#android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.close_added()). So on older platforms, the [`close()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever#close()) method does not exist, which is exactly what your crash is also saying.

On older platforms you have to (manually) call [`release()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever#release()) instead, which is what `close()` simply delegates to.

Unfortunately that means that you cannot use try-with-resources (or Kotlin's `use`) with `MediaMetadataRetriever` directly unless your minSdk is set to 29 or later.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, so I created my own subclass of MediaMetaDataRetriever in Kotlin:

```kotlin
class MyMediaMetadataRetriever : MediaMetadataRetriever(), AutoCloseable {

   override fun close() {
      release()
   }

}
```

Java (untested):

```java
public class MyMediaMetadataRetriever extends MediaMetadataRetriever implements AutoCloseable {

   public MyMediaMetadataRetriever() {
      super();
   }

   @Override
   public void close() {
      release();
   }

}
```

Comment: did you find out why?

Comment: Working well for Java, thanks.